# Rounded corners not showing on type="search" inputs

Tags: html, css

Rounded corners are snipped off when I have an input with type="search".  When I use type="text", they look great.

```
#q { padding: 8px; outline: none; width: 282px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 5px; }

<input type="search" id="q" placeholder="search..." />
```

Live here: http://jsbin.com/ilipiw/4/edit

Screenshot:

[image]

I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Just FIY it works perfectly in FF and Chrome under Linux

Comment: Because hradecek's comment (posted as an answer) was deleted, I thought I'd ask this on his behalf, in case it helps him help you: "What browser you are using ? And what about version?"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#q { -webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; outline: none; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this style for #q:

```
#q { 
    border-radius: 5px; outline: none; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 10px; 
    -webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```

This jsBin [version](http://jsbin.com/ilipiw/5/edit#source) works in Chrome 18.0.1025.162.

Answer (score -1):

Though it should work.

```
                 #q{-webkit-border-radius:5px;}
```

If this not work then update your chrome.